# VHDL compile message: array index 10 out of range

Tags: fpga, vhdl, vivado, synthesis

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_textio.all; 

entity sent_comp is 

port(
 
        iClk     : in std_logic;    
        iData    : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        oData    : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        oLed     : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0000";
        iRx_flag : in std_logic;
        oTx_flag : out std_logic:='0';
    iFlag_for_tx_state : in std_logic

    );
end entity sent_comp;
architecture behave of sent_comp is 
    
    constant cMessage_2 : string := "eror, please enter right user name  ";
    constant cMessage_1 : string := "bye word";
    constant cMessage_3 : string := "hello world"; 
    constant cM_leng_1  : integer := cMessage_1'length;
    constant cM_leng_2  : integer := cMessage_2'length; 
    constant cM_leng_3  : integer := cMessage_3'length; 
    
    type tState          is (Rx,enter,Tx);
    
    signal sState       : tState := Rx;  
    signal sIndex       : integer := 1;
    
begin 

process(iClk,iRx_flag)

    variable vLength    : integer; 
    variable vString    : string(1 to 50) := (others =>  character'val(1)); --intliazing string with null 
    variable vLoop      : integer := 1; 
    
begin 

if(rising_edge(iClk)) then  
  
    case sState is
    
        when Rx=>    
                    if(iRx_flag = '1') then 
                        oData <= iData;
                        if(iData = "00001101") then 
                            sState <= enter; 
                            oLed(1) <= '1';  
                             vLoop := 1;
                        else
                            oLed(0) <= '1'; 
                            vString(sIndex) := character'val(to_integer(unsigned(iData)));
                            sIndex <= sIndex + 1;
                            sState <= Rx;
                        end if;
                    end if; 
                    oTx_flag <= iRx_flag;   
        
        when enter=>
                    oLed(0) <= '0'; 
                    oLed(1) <= '0'; 
                    oled(2) <= '0'; 
                    sIndex <= -1;
                    for vLoop in vString'range loop  --checking every value of every index in the string
                        if(vString(vLoop) = character'val(0) ) then --if the value is null the char part of string ended and need to save the last state and length 
                            sState <= sState; 
                            vLength := vLength;
                            exit;
                        else    -- if im checking data/characters 
                            case vString(vLoop) is 
                            
                                when cMessage_1(vLoop)=> 
                                        sState <= Tx; 
                                        vLength := cM_leng_1; 
                                when cMessage_3(vLoop)=>
                                        sState <= Tx; 
                                        vLength := cM_leng_3; 
                                when others =>
                                        sState <= Rx; 
                                        oLed(2) <= '1';
                                        oLed(3) <= '0';
                                        sIndex <= 1;
                                        exit;
                            end case; 
                        end if; 
                    end loop; 
        
        when Tx=>     
                    vString := (others => character'val(1));
                    oLed(3) <= '0'; 
                    oLed(2) <= '0'; 
                    oTx_flag <= '1';
                    if(sIndex < (vLength + 2)) then  
                        sState <= Tx;
                        if(iFlag_for_tx_state = '1') then --Tx ready 
                            if(sIndex = -1) then 
                                oData <= "00001010";
                            elsif(sIndex = 0 or sIndex = (vLength + 1)) then 
                                oData <= "00001101";
                            else
                                oData <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(character'pos(vString(sIndex)), 8));      
                            end if;
                        sIndex <= sIndex + 1; 
                        end if; 
                    else -- = cmlong1 +3 
                        oTx_flag <= '0';
                        sState <= Rx; 
                        sIndex <= 1;
                        oLed(3) <= '0';
                    end if; 

                     
end case;
end if; 
end process;
end behave;
```

i have no syntax errors but thats what the compiler is saying

```
[Synth 8-97] array index 10 out of range ["C:/School/vhdl/comp_uart.vhd":78]
[Synth 8-211] could not evaluate expression: expression in case choice must be constant ["C:/School/vhdl/comp_uart.vhd":78]
[Synth 8-285] failed synthesizing module 'sent_comp' ["C:/School/vhdl/comp_uart.vhd":21]
[Common 17-69] Command failed: Vivado Synthesis failed
```

im on the vivado 2021.2.  any help would be appreciated

Comment: Actually, I would see this as a compiler error.

Comment: Your code is not standard compliant. You have case statement choices that aren't locally static (cMessage_1(vLoop), cMessage_3(vLoop)). While a case statement can be devolved into an if statement there may be other issues.

Answer (score 0):

The error message points to this line:

```vhdl
                                when cMessage_1(vLoop)=>
```

The error is that your `cMessage_1` is shorter than `vString`, as the loop runs through all its indexes:

```vhdl
                    for vLoop in vString'range loop
```